# Javascript to call element parent class

Tags: javascript, function, parent, onmouseover, onmouseout

Is this even possible?

I am using a javascipt tooltip for a site, which uses an element's onmouseover/onmouseout call to show and hide it.

```
<a class="edit active" title="Edit" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Edit');" on mouseout="tooltip.hide();">Edit</a>
<a class="swap" title="Swap" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Swap');" on mouseout="tooltip.hide();">Swap</a>
```

What I am wondering if i add another variable to the SHOW and HIDE functionality in the external javascript file, that I could somehow tell it to look for the class of the element that is calling is and implement that into the code.

EXAMPLE: In the code block above, I have two anchor tags, one has the ACTIVE class associated with it.  I wish to style, or disable, the tooltip differently for those anchor that do NOT have the ACTIVE class assigned to it.

I know it would be easy to simply add "ACTIVE" to the tooltip.show('Edit','Active'), but I was hoping for a more dynamic script that would recognize the classes itself.

Comment: I suspect you might not need JS for this, especially inline JS. CSS :hover would probably be a better solution. (This is just from what you have shown. I may be incorrect.)

Comment: The company I work for still supports IE7, so creating this solely in CSS is not an option: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6HU/